# The exact same certificate is shown as both valid and invalid on Windows

Tags: certificate

I'm trying to launch two different software, both signed with the exact same certificates. One of the program launches correctly, whereas the other asks for administrator credentials every time because it is not properly signed.

How is this possible, since it uses the exact same certificates?

See pictures below:

Valid certificate : https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1O3U.jpg

Invalid certificate : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np5hx.jpg

Comment: The invalid cert appears to be expired - expires 16 July 2014. I don't know why the other valid cert, which appears to use the same chain, is still valid. Are both on the same machine? Can you run "[sigcheck](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441.aspx) -i <file>" on both, and post the results?

Comment: Images are not in order, sorry : https://imgur.com/a/0wGrm

Comment: From the sigcheck image we see 2 differences between the unvalidating R65 CPlauncher.exe and the validating R71 CPLauncher.exe: a later though still expired certificate, and a timestamp countersigner (also expired). It's definitely different, but I still don't have a good explanation why the R71 CPLauncher.exe validates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on @Jonathan's comment:

In your "valid" case the timestamp embedded in the program signature falls within the notBefore and notAfter validity dates for the signing certificate. The signature is still valid, and the certificate used to sign it was valid at the time, so everything is copacetic.  (If codesign required a still-valid certificate you'd have to get your entire OS replaced every 15 months or so as signing certs expired).

In your second case the certificate was seemingly used for code signing after its expiration date, so the signature/certificate are considered invalid.

Here's a screenshot showing the signing time of a random DLL on my computer (signed 2015-01-25T21:47:53) with a certificate that is now expired, but CertUI shows as being happy.

[image: View of digital signature details with an expired cert]

If I were to hit the "Copy to File" button on the details tab and double click that file in explorer it'll now show it as expired, since it no longer has the context from the digital signature details dialog saying what date it should use for evaluation (so it picks the current date/time)

[image]

Comment: Indeed, for my invalid case, the timestamp is not accessible in the digital signing tab, whereas it is a date in between the notBefore and notAfter for the valid case. Thanks!